# Python script for sending an email via gmail refuses to accept username and app password?

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I'm trying to learn some email automation using python. This is my script so far:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# Email configuration
sender_email = 'sendingemail@gmail'
sender_password = 'myapppassword'
receiver_email = 'receiveremail@gmail.com'
subject = 'Subject of the Email'
message = 'This is the body of the email.'

# Create a MIMEText object to represent the email message
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender_email
msg['To'] = receiver_email
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

# Connect to the SMTP server (in this example, Gmail)
smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 587

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
    server.starttls()  # Secure the connection
    server.login(sender_email, sender_password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)
    print('Email sent successfully')
except Exception as e:
    print('Email not sent. An error occurred:', str(e))
finally:
    server.quit()
```

I keep getting this error:

> Email not sent. An error occurred: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y63-20020a253242000000b00d7497467d36sm2031898yby.45 - gsmtp')

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Wanting to set up an automation script to send an email using python. I just wanted to receive mentioned email.

Comment: _Any ideas why this isn't working_ The error says exactly why -- your credentials are incorrect.

Comment: You're using `sender_email` for both the server login and the From address.  Are you sure those are supposed to be the same?

Comment: @JohnGordon, the credentials are correct - I've validated numerous times. And yes, I'm certain they are supposed to be the same. An email always comes from the email sender, and the email I'm needing to login to is the address I'm sending from.

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The email library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: @tripleee, I'm using 3.9 but thank you for the heads up. Once I get this auth issue w gmail fixed I'll take a peek.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Google is not accepting the login because of an authentication problem. It is generally caused when two-factor authentication is on. You can log in to `https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords` to make an app-specific password. Or the better solution is to use a service like Mailgun (https://www.mailgun.com/) if you are using this for testing purposes. It's easy to set up. You can send a limited number of emails through it per day. But for learning purposes, it will be sufficient. In there you will get the settings of both api and smtp for sending emails. You can use either.

[mailgun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzZ6g.png)

Comment: I already have made an app specific password for this. It's still not accepting it for some reason.